# How to send email reminders on a particular day in appsmith

Tags: javascript, email, appsmith

I need to send email reminders on a particular day.

Scenario example -

1. I have created one form where I set notify me after 30 days.
2. Now I need to send an email reminder after 30 days.

In Appsmith how I can do that beacuse it is not a adhoc email that can be sent when user clicks on "submit" button.

Please advise.

Looked into JS functions.